# Why do the VOB files of a DVD have the same size but different play length?

Tags: video, dvd, vob

To prove my point I made a screen-shot:

[image]

My 2nd question: In order to email the content of the DVD to someone so that he/she can *just* watch the entire video (with audio) of the DVD, do I need to send all the 9 files (as shown in the screen-shot) or sending only some of them will suffice.

I want to save my bandwidth and time so any other way or method is also welcome.

Comment: You can include images directly into your question via the image button (6th button from left). I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: @mpy Thanks for doing that for me. I first tried to do the same through Images tag but it said i require 10 reputations before i directly add an image in a post.

Comment: VOBs are always 1 GB max. The playback length isn't contained within any of the individual VOB files of a DVD. How a VOB file reacts and displays itself to a DVD player is dependent on the other files that make up an authored DVD, most importantly the related IFOs. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video#Directory_and_file_structure) for details. I don't know why Win Explorer is trying to display VOB lengths (makes no sense) or where it's getting the spurious data from. It should just ignore such files IMO and concentrate on those whose metadata actually contains such info.

Answer (score 1):

The large files are needed all because this are the videos itself (including audio).

They're different in length because the video codecs work with variable bit length encoding. Therefore the same amount of images are encoded in different sized files.

Comment: Apart from that, I really doubt the play lengths given in the screen shot are correct: `00:00:05` for a 1 GB file?! (Btw. the comma in the size column is misplaced.)

Comment: @ UwePlonus 

Sorry, but it is making me more confused. 

As pointed out by @mpy , how come a 1 GB file showing only a length of 5 seconds, whereas when i run any of the four VOB files including that of 5 seconds length, they definitely run for more than their length specified. In fact, the entire DVD is of 2 hours, which is much more than the sum lengths of all 4 VOB files together.

(I have not edited the above image nor the information within, just taken the PrintScreen of the winodow explorer).

Comment: @mpy

"(Btw. the comma in the size column is misplaced.)"

the comma in the size column is NOT misplaced. In South Asian numbering system, numbers over 9,999 are written in two-digit groups rather than the three-digit groups used in most other parts of the world. Pls see this link for more details : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_numbering_system

Comment: @viv227295 Perhaps the time information is wrong. You can enter any value in the meta data and this value is not calculated on the fly. Normally this is done to confuse programms relying on this information.

Comment: @viv227295: Thanks for enlighten me about the South Asian numbering system! My comments wasn't meant offensive, it was just a lack of knowledge.

Comment: @mpy no offence taken. :)

In fact, it taught me a lesson - sometimes we need a broad perspective and be a little less prejudiced before declaring something wrong. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you probably don't want to just send the VOB files (for most DVDs this won't even work, as the files are encrypted, but this looks like it's not a commercial DVD from the title).

You'll have much better results (especially if you want to save bandwidth) by re-encoding the files in a more efficient format, using a tool such as DVD Shrink (http://www.dvdshrink.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

DVD Shrink available at the above site you mentioned is being considered as malicious by Chrome and later is not letting me download (link : http://downloadcdn.betterinstaller.com/installers/2/e/DVDShrink_downloader_by_DVDShrink.exe)

I am currently converting the DVD directly from DVD writer into AVI format through a freeware Format Factory. Hoping that this will join 9 files together and give me one reasonable size file to upload and share with someone.

Comment: Fair enough. It's been a while since I used that tool, so I'm not too sure what the reputable download sites are these days.

Comment: Format Factory did the trick. When converted to AVI, 9 files became 1 and 3.94 GB of data became 1.58 GB (around 40% reduction). And the converted file is playing as good as all the 9 files together. Now it is more convenient and economical. :)